# Why is the local variable updating a variable outside the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any reason to why h_local is updating h_global?

```
def func(n, h_local):
    if n > len(h_local) - 1:
        h_local.extend([0 for i in range(n - (len(h_local) - 1))])


h_global = [0, 2, 5, 6, 9]
func(8, h_global)
print(h_global)
```

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54645701/local-and-global-lists-in-python#:~:text=Add%20a%20comment-,1,Flag,-answered%20Feb%2012%2C%202019%20at%208%3A41)

Comment: Because they both refer to the exact same list?

Comment: Perhaps do some research on Python mutable vs. immutable objects.  You might find it quite interesting.

Comment: Also, read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2):

Python variables are just [names that refer to objects](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). `h_global` and `h_local` are two different names (in different scopes) that refer to the same list (`[0, 2, 5, 6, 9]`) that was first created when the name `h_global` was defined.

When the function is called, it essentially performs the following assignment:

```
h_local = h_global
```

which just makes `h_local` another name for the list `h_global` already refers to.

Inside the function, the `extend` methods adds values to that `list`; which name is used to invoke the method is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(n, h_local):
```

Have you ever programmed with `C`/`C++`? Do you know what does it mean that an *object is passed by reference*?

In this case `h_local` is an argument of a **`mutable` type**, which in Python is treated as if it was passed by reference.

---

In C++ you may see something like this:

```
void function(int passed_by_value, int& passed_by_reference) {
    passed_by_value++;
    passed_by_reference++;
}
```

In this case, when calling `function` on two variables, the first argument won't be changed, while the second one will.

In Python you don't have the passage for reference, but you have the mutable types.
When you pass an instance of a mutable type to a function it's like passing it by reference.

---

You can find an explaination [`here`](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/python/what-are-mutable-and-immutable-data-types-in-python/), try doing the same thing as you are doing but using an **immutable** type, and you will see the original variable passed to the function won't be changed at the end.

---

> *That is, if you pass an immutable value, the parameter still references the exact same object (no copy is made); that fact that you can't change it is inherent in the object itself, not in how it was passed to the function.*

**This** is the most correct explaination of why you can't do this with immutable type objects.

Comment: Immutable types are treated the exact same way. Python argument-passing semantics are neither call-by-value nor call-by-reference, but something in between.

Comment: That is, if you pass an immutable value, the parameter still references the *exact same object* (no copy is made); that fact that you can't change it is inherent in the object itself, not in how it was passed to the function.

Comment: Right, if you want feel free to improve the description editing the answer.